# How to convert a string contains array format to java array or list?

Tags: java

I have a string like this:

```
String res = '["A","B","0","1"]';
```

How to convert it to an array or list in Java to become like this:

```
String[] r = {"A","B","0","1"};
```

Comment: are the `"` _actually_ a part of the string ?

Comment: Remove the first and last characters, split on the comma, remove the quotes around each element. The javadoc of String is your friend: it has substring, and split.

Comment: This is not a java string. Please provide a compiling example.

Comment: @YassinHajaj , originally i receive the data from request as xml format, like this:

<row data='  ["A","B","0","1"]  ' />  

by parsing it i get string in that format. witch i want to convert it to Java array.

Comment: @Aominè no, I only want to get the value A,B,0,1 as a Stings

Comment: what is your exact input?

Comment: @Pradeep the exact input is ["A","B","0","1"], i get it from in attribute of an element of XML like this:  <row data=' ["A","B","0","1"] ' />.

Comment: the first string is an array in json format. you can parse it with Gson and retrieve the string array directly

Comment: @Daniele, if i didn't find any normal way, i will try to read about json and how to parse it.

Comment: @YounessNachid-Idrissi see jferard's response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using `Gson`, You can get the desired result by following below approach -

```
String inputStr = "[\"A\",\"B\",\"0\",\"1\"]";
        String[] strArray = inputStr.split("[^\\w\\d]");
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String str : strArray) {
            if (str != null && !str.isEmpty()) {
                list.add(str);
            }
        }
System.out.println(list);
```

> Output will be: [A, B, 0, 1]

Comment: That it's really what i was looking for, no need to search about Gson and how to enabled it in my environment for just to do this task.

Comment: It seems very fragile: you assume that the list will only contain elements composed of letters or digits (or an underscore). Note that `\d` is included in `\w`, and that you could just use `inputStr.split("\\W")`.

Answer (score 2):

Since your string is a correct Json string, you may use the [`gson`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson) library:

```
String s = "[\"A\",\"B\",\"0\",\"1\"]";
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
String[] arr = gson.fromJson(s, String[].class);
// {"A","B","0","1"}
```

Comment: it gives me package com.google.gson dose not exist.

i'm using Geany on Ubuntu. i don't have this package by default right now.

Comment: @YounessNachid-Idrissi If you're using maven (or a similar build tool), just add the dependency to your pom.xml. Else, you have to download the jar and to add it to your classpath manually.

Comment: @YounessNachid-Idrissi you can get it from http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.5/gson-2.8.5.jar

Answer (score 0):

```
   String res = "[A,B,0,1]";
    res = res.replace("[", "");
    res = res.replace("]", "");
    res = res.replaceAll(",", "");
    String [] arrayOutput = new String [res.length()];
    char [] ar = res.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i< ar.length; i++) 
    {
        char buffer = ar[i];
        arrayOutput[i] =  String.valueOf(buffer);           
    }
```

Comment: this is works only for that input you write, my input came from a request server like this ["A","B","0","1"];